# TCP connection socket timeout

Tags: timeout, xmpp

I'm having an issue with my server, where XMPP server (MongooseIM) send times out.

Scenario: MongooseIM runs on EC2, user connects first time, it connects perfectly. Then, i disable this connection, and try to connect with same user. Error that i get.

```
1404224951 [INFO]: Connecting to tcp://xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5222
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5222 (Connection timed out) in /home/ubuntu/xmppphp/XMPPHP/XMLStream.php on line 313
1404224981 [ERROR]: Could not connect.
```

However, when i wait more than 10 min, i can connect without any problem. I've used this guide to tweak TCP settings, i believe that's the error. [Guide to TCP tweaking](http://www.nateware.com/linux-network-tuning-for-2013.html#.U7LBG3WSxhG)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you seeing anything inside of `MongooseIM` logs?

Comment: I only see this: <0.268.0>@shaper_srv:handle_info:114 Deleted old shapers.